# How to change from a UITableViewController to a ViewController within a button in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

Hello I am a beginner/intermediate user at Objective-C and Xcode but I am wondering, can someone please provide a source for changing views from a UITableViewController to a ViewContoller? I've tried about everything and nothing is working. I've tried calling a Segue using performseguewithidentifier but it's not working I guess cause it's a UITableViewController and not a ViewController. So if someone could help me I'd really appreciate that, thanks.

Comment: UITableViewController **is** a UIViewContoller

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //push the view controller to a navigationController
}
```